# Using JAR files aliases in Windows cmd

Tags: java, windows, cmd, jar, alias

I've recently created a program called `sayHello.jar` (that greets the specfified name) which I can call on command line with `java -jar sayHello.jar [name]`. I obviously need to be in the same directory as the file, so I want to know how is it possible to execute this program with the command like `sayHello [name]` from any directory in the PC, just like I can do with e.g. `javac` or `git init`.

I was thinking about using environment variables, but I guess they only work with *.exe* files.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file named `sayHello.cmd` in a directory that is on the `PATH`, and write the following using any text editor of your choice:

```
@java -jar C:\path\to\sayHello.jar %*
```

Since the file is on the path, you can now run the code using:

```
sayHello [name]
```

Comment: I can call the file from the same folder just by saying `sayHello [name]` now, but the environment variable doesn't seem to work - it still doesn't recognize the command. I add the path to `Path` system variable, and set it to `C:\path` , should I specify the exact program path like `C:\path\say.cmd`?

Comment: @skorejen What environment variable? I didn't say to change or use any environment variable, only to place the `.cmd` file in a folder already on the `PATH`, e.g. `C:\Windows`. --- If you're talking about `PATH` and you change the `PATH` in Control Panel > System, then you need to reopen the Command Prompt window for the new path value to take effect.

Comment: I've put it in `C:\Windows` now and it works perfect and is amazing! Thank you so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `PATHEXT` environment variable to include `.jar`. Make sure you leave what is already there, and make another semicolon-delimited entry. Also, make sure that `assoc .jar` returns `.jar=jarfile` and `ftype jarfile` returns `jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*` or something similar.

Comment: `ftype jarfile` returns `jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*`, (jre instead of jdk) but apart from that everything is same. I tried to assign the file dir into the env variable, but I still get `C:\Users\skorejen\Documents\sayHello>say Daniel
'say' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Since those instructions leaves the `.jar` extension running the `javaw` command, not the `java` command, you won't be able to see the command-line output, because there is no command-line output from a *windowed* process.